# random value in twodimensional array in c

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

Okay so, I have a twodimensional array of int's, which in create using this:

```
int **matrix;
matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++) {
    matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

Now I set every field to 0.
The next step is to fill it with values. Therefore I read values from a file I already opened.

```
while (fscanf(f2, "%s -> %[^;\n]%*c", start, ziel) == 2) {
    intomatrix(start, ziel, &graph);
}
```

intomatrix just alters the data and puts it in the matrix using

```
matrix[start][ziel] = 1;
```

Now when I set manually (not using the while-loop)

```
matrix[2][0] = 1
```

and print the matrix. Not only is (2,0) but also (0,4) set to 1.
There should be now way in which matrix[0][4] is used.

This also happens with other fields. (2,0) also sets (1,4).

Comment: `matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));` allocates for array of 1 element. Should be `matrix[i] = malloc(ELEMENTS*sizeof(int));`

Comment: wow... @WeatherVane that was the problem. Now its solved. Thx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should this:

```
matrix[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

be an array of integers vs. just one? If not you have multiple rows but just one column.